# Assign parent class object to inherited class object in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I can catch the physicsBody.node when I detect collision between two SKSpriteNode-s on my scene. However, I know for sure that collided objects are some of my own objects that actually inherit the SKSpriteNode. One of them that gets collided is, for instance, StaticLevelElement. Now, I want that SKNode to be assigned to my StaticLevelElement * sle, by some conversion or some other way.

```
StaticLevelElement * staticLevelElement = notTheHero.node;
```

Notice that here notTheHero.node is my StaticLevelElement. This actually works but gives my warning:
"Incompatible pointer types initializing 'StaticLevelElement' with an expression of type 'SKNode'......."
I don't want this warning and want to do it properly so it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
StaticLevelElement * staticLevelElement = (StaticLevelElement*)notTheHero.node;
```

It is called type casting. Note that this doesn't change the underlying instance. The instance is just treated in a different way.

For example, if the underlying instance is SKNode or its subclass , but not specifically the `StaticLevelElement`, the app may crash if you try to use it as `StaticLevelElement`.

So if you are completely sure that casting will not fail, then it is safe to do it.